# Too many pages using kaminari gem in Ruby on Rails 3.1 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I am using the kaminari pagination gem in my simple Rails 3.1 application. Problem is it creates too many pages, I end up with completly blank pages at the end of my page list.

I have experimented in the console with:

```
current_user.articles
```

Which returns me a list of 6 articles, the same as the ones being displayed in my application.

```
current_user.articles.count
```

Which returns me "8", is it this number that the number of pages is based on?

```
current_user.articles.length
```

Returns me "6"

```
current_user.articles.size
```

Returns me "8"

Is this discrepency between the number of articles causing my problem? Where is the problem, and how do I fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug, solution is [here](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/pull/160).

Answer (score 1):

I guess your `User#articles` is not just an ordinal `has_many`, so we need a bit more info to see what's actually happening.
Could you show us `current_user.articles.scoped.to_sql`?